# Why KJV translates 1 Cor. 7:3's ὀφείλω as "due benevolence" and not "debt"?

Tags: greek, 1-corinthians, kjv, marriage

Why does the KJV translate the [ὀφείλω](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=greek&l=%E1%BD%80%CF%86%CE%B5%E1%BD%B7%CE%BB%CF%89#lexicon) of 1 Cor. 7:3 as "due benevolence" and not "debt"?

KJV:

> Let the husband render unto the wife due benevolence (οφειλομένην?): and likewise also the wife unto the husband.

cf. [Rheims version (transl. of Latin Vulgate)](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=53&ch=7&l=3-#x):

> Let the husband render the debt (οφειλομένην) to his wife, and the wife also in like manner to the husband.
> <sub>*Uxori vir debitum* (οφειλομένην) *reddat : similiter autem et uxor viro.*</sub>

Comment: My extended Liddel & Scott (1864) 1,700 pages gives 'the wider meaning' of ὀφειλὴν as 'to be under an obligation' or to 'have a duty'. It is not _exactly_ a matter of indebtedness, as such. Quite why the KJV translators chose 'due benevolence' I cannot say, therefore this is only a comment not an answer. But that is my own outlook within marriage : it is a matter of benevolent duty, not a legal debt of covenant.

Comment: Because that's what it meant: due benel., conjugal rights, affection owed, marital duty, affection owed, NLT more unnecessarily explicit "sexual needs".

Answer (score 1):

The operative word (noun) in 1 Cor 7:3 is ὀφειλή (ὀφειλή) for which BDAG provides two meanings for the just three occurrences in the NT. [There is also a textual problem in 1 Cor 7:3 of ὀφειλὴν = "obligation", vs, ὀφειλομένην εὔνοιαν = "affection being owed" in this verse; for details, see NA28.].  Here I will assume the NA28/UBS5 text of ὀφειλὴν.

1. **that which one owes in a financial sense, *obligation***; as debt (...) eg, Matt 18:32, Pl of taxes and imposts, Rom 13:7, This pass. demonstrates the easy transference to
2. **that which one ought to do, *duty***, of that which is appropriate in a social relationship; obligation of pleasing one's spouse conjugally, 1 Cor 7:3. Pl, of respect and honor, Rom 13:7 ...

The cognate verb, ὀφείλω (used very widely in the NT) has a similar breadth of meaning that encompasses (1) to be indebted, Matt 18:28, (2) to be under obligation to meet certain social or moral expectations, Rom 13:8, Luke 17:10, John 19:7, etc, (3) to be constrained by circumstances, 1 Cor 5:10, 2 Cor 12:11.

Note the comments of Barnes:

> Let the husband ... - "Let them not imagine that there is any virtue
> in bring separate from each other, as if they were in a state of
> celibacy" - "Doddridge." They are bound to each other; in every way
> they are to evince kindness, and to seek to promote the happiness and
> purity of each other. There is a great deal of delicacy used here by
> Paul, and his expression is removed as far as possible from the
> grossness of pagan writers. His meaning is plain; but instead of using
> a word to express it which would be indelicate and offensive, he uses
> one which is not indelicate in the slightest degree. The word which he
> uses εὔνοιαν eunoian," benevolence") denotes kindness, good-will,
> affection of mind. And by the use of the word "due" ὀφειλομένην
> opheilomenēn, he reminds them of the sacredness of their vow, and of
> the fact that in person, property, and in every respect, they belong
> to each other. It was necessary to give this direction, for the
> contrary might have been regarded as proper by many who would have
> supposed there was special virtue and merit in living separate from
> each other; as facts have shown that many have imbibed such an idea -
> and it was not possible to give the rule with more delicacy than Paul
> has done.

The Pulpit commentary is more succinct:

> Paul is evidently entering on these subjects, not out of any love for
> them; but because all kinds of extreme views - immoral indifference
> and over scrupulous asceticism - had claimed dominance among the
> Corinthians.

Answer (score 1):

My extended Liddel & Scott (1864) 1,700 pages gives 'the wider meaning' of οφειλην as :

> 'to be under an obligation' or to 'have a duty'.

It is not exactly a matter of indebtedness, as such. Quite why the KJV translators chose 'due benevolence' I cannot say.

But that is my own outlook within marriage : it is a matter of benevolent duty, not a legal debt of covenant.